# Was Felicity Jones (Jyn Erso) considered for the role of Rey?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, rogue-one, behind-the-scenes, actors

Let's face it, they look similar enough and have similar accents.

And Jones seems to have received critical acclaim for *Rogue One*.

And you'd better believe Disney took the job of casting the sequel trilogy very very seriously.

At the time, was Felicity Jones known and considered?

If yes, what were the reasons behind the decision to go with Daisy Ridley?

Comment: Umm, explanation for downvotes, please?   I can't see why anyone wouldn't think this is a completely legitimate question.

Comment: I didn't vote, but questions of this type often carry an emotional tinge that make them opinion based, or perhaps seeking validation of personal preferences.  "Why didn't they cast Christopher Walken as Morpheus?  Look at the man dance!  He's an utter badass!  What kind of a director would cast Laurence Fishburne instead?!?"  I'm not saying that's the question you're asking, but at first blush it hits some of the same notes.

Comment: @gowenfawr:   That interpretation doesn't affect the validity of the question.   The question is just, Was she considered?   I can happily remove the potentially offending sentence if it is that offensive to people.

Answer (score 14):

### Is there anything to suggest that she was?

The closest thing I found is Saoirse Ronan saying

> “Yeah, I did [audition for Star Wars Episode VII]… I don’t know whether I should have said that now! **I mean, everyone did. Everyone has auditioned for it.** So many people I know have gone in for the part I’ve gone in for, and guys who’ve gone in for a particular part, so I’d imagine J.J. is probably just scanning the earth to find the people that he needs.” - [empireonline.com](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/exclusive-saoirse-ronan-star-wars-episode-vii-audition/)

It doesn't sound like she was seriously considered though, supposedly the three other names that stand out were Elizabeth Olsen, Jennifer Lawrence and Shailene Woodley as non-picks.

> Elizabeth Olsen, Jennifer Lawrence and Shailene Woodley were considered for the role of Rey, which went to Daisy Ridley. Olsen refused the audition because she had a contract with Marvel Studios for the role of Scarlet Witch in the Avengers’ franchise and because the shoot dates for The Force Awakens clashed with Age of Ultron. In April 2014, J.J. Abrams chose Ridley as Rey. - [news.com.au](http://www.news.com.au/entertainment/movies/hollywood-actors-who-rejected-roles-in-the-star-wars-films/news-story/e92cef7799569e15425c83a0ffa533a9)

Casting for Rogue One didn't start until Spring of 2015

> Back in the spring of 2015, even fresh off the acclaim for "The Theory of Everything," there was no certainty that Jones would be the one cavorting with Stormtroopers. Equally established actors Rooney Mara and Tatiana Maslany were also reportedly circling the part.
>
> Edwards now admits he was prepared to enlist Jones from the very beginning. It didn't hurt that they grew up just a few miles apart in the British Midlands and shared a similar sense of humor. - [nydailynews.com](http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/movies/felicity-jones-credits-force-rogue-role-article-1.2906141)

### So I'll say no.

With two different directors, each one had their own idea what they were looking for. JJ was looking for Daisy Ridley, and Edwards wanted Felicity Jones.

Comment: Boy am I relieved it wasn't Jennifer Lawrence or Shailene Woodley.   I guess Elizabeth Olsen would have been okay.   But relative unknowns are the right choice.